# Import YUV as a byte array

Tags: python, numpy, yuv

I'm working on a project where I have to apply threshold to a YUV420_SP_NV21 image (taken from an Android camera) to determine which pixels are 'black' and which are 'white'.

Therefore, I want to import it in Python as a bytearray (using OpenCV, NumPy, PIL, ...), so I can do some quick bitwise operations on the Y-values.

However, when I try to import the image using the following methods, I get useless outputs:

When I type

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test.yuv')
imgArr = np.array(img)

print(img)
print(imgArr)
```

I get as output:

```
None
None
```

And when I type

```
import numpy as np

f = open('test.yuv', 'rb')
img = f.read()
imgArr = np.array(img)
```

I get some useless character sequence. 
And when I type now (for exemple)

```
print(imgArr[0])
```

I get as output:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Which means imgArr is no array at all!

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be better if you could provide us with a sample YUV file

Comment: YUV format doesn't encode the image width and height, so you will need to provide a sample file and also the height and width of the image in pixels, YUV encodes at 1.5 bytes per pixel, so if your image is 80x40 pixels that makes 3,200 pixels and the file should be 4,800 bytes (3,200 * 1.5) in size. Thanks.

Comment: "... some useless character sequence". I find it hard to come up with something you could reasonably have expected. The image in text form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really should provide a sample image so folks can help you better - else they spend ages developing code for what they guess is the image format you mean and it is a waste of effort if they guess wrong.

Assuming your data look like this from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV), you can see that all the Y samples come first, followed by all the U samples and all the V samples. However there are only 1/4 as many U/V samples as Y samples because these two components are subsampled at 2:1 ratio both horizontally and vertically:

[image]

So, the idea is to read in the entire set of YUV samples, then take the first `w*h` bytes as the Y values, the next `w*h/4` samples as U and the next `w*h/4` samples as V:

```
import numpy as np

# Guess a width and height and derive number of pixels in image
w,h = 2048,1536
px = w*h

# Read entire file into YUV
YUV = np.fromfile('NV21_2048x1536.yuv',dtype='uint8')

# Take first h x w samples and reshape as Y channel
Y = YUV[0:w*h].reshape(h,w)

# Take next px/4 samples as U
U = YUV[px:(px*5)//4].reshape(h//2,w//2)

# Take next px/4 samples as V
V = YUV[(px*5)//4:(px*6)//4].reshape(h//2,w//2)

# Undo subsampling of U and V by doubling height and width
Ufull = U.copy().resize((w,h))
Vfull = V.copy().resize((w,h))
```

I have no idea what you plan to do next, so I'll leave it at that for now!

---

**Keywords**: NV21, YUV, YUV420, Android, YUV430P, Pillow, PIL, Python, image, image processing.

Comment: The key to my problem was the **np.fromfile()** function.

I knew the byte stream order but didn't think it was important for the question. I only didn't know how to import the file as an array of bytes (represented as numbers between 0 and 255).

But still, thanks for your structured answer

Comment: I used this code to convert YUV to RGB. I found it useful the info to extract the vector Y, U and V, but then followed the answer to this question to understand how to correctly obtain the RGB matrix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752839/decoding-a-yuv-image-in-python-opencv